# Angular2 RC1 loading issue - SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: angular

I am trying to update my application from Angular 2 beta 18 to Angular2 RC1, I already changed imports, fix a lot of syntax errors and now, I am getting this error when the app is loading. Also Angular2 quickstart does not work!

```
zone.js:323 Error: (SystemJS) SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    Evaluating http://localhost:8080/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic
    Error loading http://localhost:8080/app/ts/main.component.js
```

My main components is:

```
import {bootstrap} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

I found this https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-dragula/issues/274, but I have no idea, what it means, where to search for require etc. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to describe to your module loader (SystemJS) how your app is structured, so it knows where to look for files when it resolves your imports. Right now it looks for `main.component.js` in `app/ts/` folder, and your server returns default file (probably `index.html`) which SystemJS doesn't understand (first character in index.html is `<`).

To configure SystemJS, add [`map`](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/config-api.md#map) and/or [`packages`](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/config-api.md#packages) properties to the `config` object in `system-config.js`

```
System.config({
  map: { 
    // when I ask for 'app' look for it in 'path/to/app` folder
    app: 'path/to/app' 
  },
  // describe 'app' package, so System knows how to handle it
  // look at docs for options...
  packages: { 
    app: {
      // if you compiled ts to CommonJS module
      format: 'cjs'
    }
  },
});
```

I suggest you look at some examples of working apps and see how they are configured, or use tools that handle configuration for you, like [Angular CLI](https://cli.angular.io/).